# iOS - How is that change of TextView frame makes it's text after pdf export unselectable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pdf-generation, uitextview

**How is that change of textView frame makes it's text after pdf export unselectable?** It's simple rasterized with horible compression. If I export textView and don't change the frame I got perfect vectors.

I've view with textView and I export the pdf with content of textView like this:

```
- (void) generatePDFWithFilename:(NSString *)filename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    //  pdf view
    _pdfView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792)];

    //  adding subview - for easier positioning
    CGRect tempFrame;
    UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, _pdfView.bounds.size.width - 20, _pdfView.bounds.size.height - 20)];
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    _pdfView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [_pdfView addSubview:tempView];


    UITextView *pdfDescriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    pdfDescriptionTextView = _workDescriptionTextView;
    [tempView addSubview:pdfDescriptionTextView];
    // pdfDescriptionTextView.center = CGPointMake(50, 200); // working - vector data are preserved
    tempFrame = pdfDescriptionTextView.frame;
    tempFrame.origin = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    tempFrame.size = CGSizeMake(tempView.bounds.size.width - 40, pdfDescriptionTextView.contentSize.height);
    pdfDescriptionTextView.frame = tempFrame;
    pdfDescriptionTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(_pdfView.bounds, nil);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [_pdfView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    BOOL success = [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    if(success)
    {
        [self sendEmailWithData:pdfData];
    }
}
```

[image: frame NOT changed - vector data]
[image: frame changed - rasterized text]

Comment: u want to make the textview data as pdf  .....u can try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066231/create-multipage-pdf-directly-from-uitextview-in-ipad/15068235#15068235

Comment: I can do that, see the picures - those are pdf screenshots. but one is with vector fonts and the other with rasterized - regarding if frame was changed or not

Answer (score -1):

just change its editing mode.....

```
pdfDescriptionTextView.editable = FALSE;
```

After this the user will not be able to change the text anymore

Comment: no, I'm talking about text in exported pdf, not UITextView in my app.

Comment: I simply need vector data after export, If I change UITextView frame I got only rasterized text