# Swift converted to PDF but not stops

Tags: swift, pdf, textview

I want to generate pdf from textview after user enters the data. The textview contains paragraphs and attributed texts.
I have Followed
[this procedure](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/09/07/create-pdf-in-ios/)

and my code is:

```
func createPdf() {
    createPDFNamed("test")         
}

func getPDFPath(_ name: String) -> String {
    let newPDFName = "\(name).pdf"
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let pdfPath: String = (documentsDirectory as String).appending(newPDFName);
    print(pdfPath)
    return pdfPath
}

func createPDFNamed(_ name: String) {
    let text = myTextView.text              
    let currentText: CFAttributedString = CFAttributedStringCreate(nil, (text as CFString?), nil)
    if currentText != nil {
        let framesetter: CTFramesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText)
        if framesetter != nil {
            let pdfFileName: String = getPDFPath(name)
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRect.zero, nil)
            var currentRange: CFRange! = CFRangeMake(0, 0)
            var currentPage: Int = 0
            var done = false
            repeat {
                UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 612, height: 792), nil)
                currentPage += 1
                drawPageNbr(currentPage)
                currentRange = renderPagewithTextRange(currentRange, andFramesetter: framesetter)
                if currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength((currentText as? CFAttributedString)) {
                    done = true
                }
            } while !done
            UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        }
        else {
            print("Could not create the framesetter needed to lay out the atrributed string.")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Could not create the attributed string for the framesetter")
    }
}

func renderPagewithTextRange(_ currentRange: CFRange, andFramesetter framesetter: CTFramesetter) -> CFRange {
    var currentRange: CFRange! = CFRangeMake(0, 0)
    let currentContext: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    currentContext?.textMatrix = .identity
    let frameRect = CGRect(x: 72, y: 72, width: 468, height: 648)
    let framePath: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    framePath.addRect(frameRect, transform: .identity)

    let frameRef: CTFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, nil)
    currentContext?.translateBy(x: 0, y: 792)
    currentContext?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext!)
    currentRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frameRef)
    currentRange.location += currentRange.length
    currentRange.length = 0 as? CFIndex ?? CFIndex()
    return currentRange
}

func drawPageNumber(_ pageNum: Int) {
    let pageString = "Page \(Int(pageNum))"
    let theFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    let pageStringSize: CGSize = pageString.size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
    let stringRect = CGRect(x: ((612.0 - pageStringSize.width) / 2.0), y: 720.0 + ((72.0 - pageStringSize.height) / 2.0), width: pageStringSize.width, height: pageStringSize.height)
    let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableParagraphStyle
    paragraphStyle?.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    paragraphStyle?.alignment = .right                
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: theFont, .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle as Any] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    pageString.draw(in: stringRect, withAttributes: attributes)
}
```

The pdf generates and never ends even it went upto 2Gb file size. But not opening. Could you please advice where I am doing mistake to finish the pdf generation? Also after pdf creation, would like to send by mail
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
If I change the code to `while done` it stops but prints one page only. If I change to `while !done` it goes on generating pdf. Past two days searching and not end up with any solution. Also the pdf prints black only. I want to reflect the attributes to pdf. Any suggestions.

```
if (currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength(currentText)){
                        done = true
                    }
                } while done
                    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
                }
                    else  {
                    print("Could not create the framesetter needed to lay out the atrributed string.")
                }
            }
                else  {
                print("Could not create the attributed string for the framesetter")
            }
            }
```

Comment: You have a `repeat {} while` loop where the stopping is condition is `if currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength((currentText as? CFAttributedString))`. Mind printing `currentRange.location`, `currentText as? CFAttributedString` and `CFAttributedStringGetLength((currentText as? CFAttributedString))`? It could help you understand what's wrong.

Comment: @Larme still not successful the method to achieve. Will you please guide me?

Comment: Your code don't stop the loop because `if currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength((currentText as? CFAttributedString))` is never true. Check the values!

Comment: changed as recommended [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15068235/2513756] and printing all the pages